# CKAN: Bad password in web interface but REST API works?

Tags: ckan, repoze.who

I installed CKAN from the package then reconfigured it to serve only through Apache. Everything worked great at first, but now I can't log into the web interface. I can create a user, but they get an error:

> Login failed. Bad username or password.

Password reset works, but they still can't log in. Repoze.who is not logging anything at all, so I don't know what's up. The weird thing is I can use the REST API with the api-key for the user (obtained through paster) and get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very tough to answer without more information. There is a real possibility that the password is somehow being submitted wrong.

One suggestion would be to reset the password from the command line with a specific password and see what happens (use `paster user -h` to see options for managing users from command line).

Comment: I've tried that, but I think I've narrowed down the problem to an issue with WSGI (it works properly if the page is served via 'ckan serve'). I'm using the standard configuration that comes with the package, except with the port value changed to 80 and ServerName changed to my FQDN

Comment: Are you proxying the app? You may need to make sure credentials are forwarded appropriately.

Comment: Just remembered that I never actually posted to this when I figured it out. It turns out the server was mangling requests due to hardware issues. An install on a different box worked perfectly.